# PDF READER IN IOS(OBJECTIVE _C)

Tags: qlpreviewcontroller

User can change the page, zoom in - zoom out the page. We only need a special animation for page change event like a physical page flip.

Comment: what you want to know? a pdf reader in android?

Comment: pdf reader in ios i mentioned in title like objective-c